# Angular 2 Http Get return type 3 error on body

Tags: angular, http

i have a problem when i try to return a response from asp.core api
"angular 2 http get Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: {…}, type: 3, url: null }"

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IIndustryType } from '../../../model/IndustryType';
import { DeveloperJobDataService }from'../../../services/developerjob.dataservice';

@Component({
    selector: 'add-job',
    templateUrl: './addJob.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./addJob.component.css'],
    providers: [DeveloperJobDataService]
})
export class AddJobComponent {
    errorMessage: string;
    private industry: IIndustryType[];

    constructor(private dataService: DeveloperJobDataService) {
        this.dataService.GetIndustries().subscribe(result => {
            this.industry = result.json() as IIndustryType[];
            console.log(this.industry);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
export interface IIndustryType {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    isActive: boolean,
    createdDate: Date
}
```

Services:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { IIndustryType } from '../model/IndustryType';
import { IndustryType } from '../model/viewModel';

@Injectable()

export class DeveloperJobDataService {
    private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:49861/api/Industries';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public GetIndustries() {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: what can you add a `console.log(result);` inside the subscribe method in the component? And give me the out put

Comment: The same result....
GET http://localhost:49861/api/Industries 200 (OK)
Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
type
:
3
url
:
null
_body
:
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 1, total: 0, type: "error", …}
__proto__
:
Body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed HTTP method in `requestOptions` like this:

https://angular.io/api/http/Http#request

Your example doesn't have the post body; I guess you want to use Http Get. if it's not, you can change [HttpMethod](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestMethod)  for your situation

```js
  public GetIndustries() {
     return this.http.request(this.baseUrl,{
         method : 'Get' // or 'Post'
     });
  }
```

or you can use `get` instead of `request`

```js
public GetIndustries() {
   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
}
```

Comment: The same result if i put "get"

Comment: would you get result `http://localhost:49861/api/Industries` from chrome or any browser in your local environment?

Comment: Ok, i resolved, the problem was with the back end EF and dataBase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

change your `GetIndustries` method like this.

```
public GetIndustries() Observable<IIndustryType[]>{
        return this.http.get<IIndustryType[]>(this.baseUrl);
}
```

And in your component constructor where you call the `GetIndustries` methhod do these changes.

```
 constructor(private dataService: DeveloperJobDataService) {
        this.dataService.GetIndustries().subscribe(result => {
            this.industry = result;
            console.log(this.industry);
        }, error => console.error(error));
 }
```